# how to show method / function list in Textmate

Tags: macos, lua, textmate, coronasdk

I am working on a Lua file. I have some methods in it. I wanted to know if its possible to configure Textmate to show the list of methods inside a file and a way to quickly reach the first line of a method by choosing a method from that list. I do have Lua and Corona specific Textmate bundle installed for syntax highlighting Lua and Corona APIs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what a bummer. Found the answer. Its in the bottom pane of Textmate window. Next to tab size.

Answer (score 5):

A quick shortcut would be to ⇧⌘T or go to Navigate -> Go to Symbol.